# Proper way to update GUI after receiving real time data from socket - iOS

Tags: ios, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

So I'm using GCDAsyncSocket for an iOS app.  It runs on GCD thread.  When data is received by the socket it changes the game state, which is stored in a shared data model called Game (Game uses synchronize to prevent data corruption).  My question is, what is the proper way to inform the GUI that changes have been made?

If I have the data model "Game" notify the controller for the GUI, won't that run the updates on the GCD thread and thus cause problems?

If I'm way off just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Use NSNotification for example

Comment: "In a multithreaded application, notifications are always delivered in the thread in which the notification was posted, which may not be the same thread in which an observer registered itself." - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html

I don't think thats what I want.  The GCD thread would be performing the updates wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// update UI, this runs on Main thread.
});
```

OR:

```
[anObject performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateUI) withObject:anObjectOrNil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: Will calling "dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()" from the main thread already have any negative effects?  Like can I just write my update UI methods all wrapped in that?

Comment: It has no direct negative effect, but instead of this you should state rules like, data fetching is operating on thread1, business logic on thread2, and UI update on the main thread and use dispatching whenever these modules communicates with each other, and use direct calls inside the modules.